# Invite friends with Javascript, but inside a specific page of a canvas app

Tags: javascript, facebook, canvas, invite

What I need to do is to put a button on various pages of my facebook app, which will invite user's friends to the specific page of the app.

I use the JS SDK of facebook and I created the following function:

```
<script>
function sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelector() {
    FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
        title: 'Share message title',
        message: 'Share message'
    }, requestCallback);
}
function requestCallback(response) {
}
</script>
```

I am thinking that I might need to add the "redirect_uri", but whatever I did it didn't work. The app uses clean urls.

I have to tell you that my app is still in Sandbox mode and I also have set basic Authenticated Referrals for the users. Also the Migrations settings are as follows:

```
Stream post URL security: Disabled
Deprecate offline access: Enabled
Timezone-less events: Enabled
Forces use of login secret for auth.login: Disabled
Enhanced Auth Dialog: Enabled
Page Hours Format: Enabled
Batch API Exceptions Format: Enabled
July 2012 Breaking Changes: Disabled
Include Checkins with Statuses: Enabled
```

Do you need more information on that so that you can help me find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried it before, but the [Requests Dialog documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) has something about the data parameter which is optional:

> Optional, additional data you may pass for tracking. This will be
>   stored as part of the request objects created. The maximum length is
>   255 characters.

Also, you can see how it's used in this official facebook blog post: [Upgrade to Requests 2.0](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/464/)

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you. The official blog post helped. Although that I had an extra problem. If the FB app has "Authenticated Referrals" enabled, then  invitation leads the user to the auhtentication page. When the user accepts it, the request id of the invitation is lost. Any idea on that?

Comment: Umm, yeah, I see what you're saying.. I don't know what to tell you though, I've never faced this problem before and the docs have nothing to say regarding this issue. You might want to consider creating a [bug report](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs)